# Django approximate matching of unicode strings with ascii equivalents

Tags: django, unicode, ascii, matching, approximate

I have the following model and instance:

```
class Bashable(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

>>> foo = Bashable.objects.create(name=u"piñata")
```

Now I want to be able to search for objects, but using ascii characters rather than unicode, something like this:

```
>>> Bashable.objects.filter(name__lookslike="pinata")
```

Is there a way in Django to do this sort of approximate string matching, using ascii stand-ins for the unicode characters in the database?

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881936/matching-an-approximate-string-in-a-core-data-store), but for Apple's Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching against a "de-accented" list of names if the initial search fails. Here's a php remove_accents function that could be translated into python easily: [remove_accents()](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php.source.html#l521)

```
query = u"pinata"
r = Bashable.objects.filter(name=query)
if not r:
    accented = Bashable.objects.values('id', 'name')
    match_ids = [ obj['id'] for obj in accented 
                                if query in remove_accents(obj['name']) ]
    r = Blog.objects.in_bulk(match_ids)
return r
```

And here's a stackoverflow entry on fuzzy string matching in python: [#682367](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682367/good-python-modules-for-fuzzy-string-comparison)

Comment: This looks like a reasonable solution.  It would be nice to be able to do this more efficiently at the database level in a single query, but it looks as though PostgreSQL at least doesn't support it (haven't checked the others).  Pace's solution[1] points to the implementation of accent stripping.

  [1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480159/django-approximate-matching-of-unicode-strings-with-ascii-equivalents/2480313#2480313

Answer (score 1):

The first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410308/how-to-implement-unicode-string-matching-by-folding-in-python) shows how to use the `strip_accents` function which is a python function to achieve what you want.  It's not technically part of Django but it is built into Python.